# QGIS: Using Filter expression for Drop Down Lists in Value Relation Widget

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, filter, widget

I have a vector layer and want to enable the user to pick values from drop-down lists. The values of the drop-down list change depending on the chosen value of the previous field(s). It works perfectly if the value changes depending on the value of one field. In my case, it is depending on two fields actually.

Therefore I tried added this in the filter expression

```
 "HWFDB-Massnahmenart"  =  current_value('hwfdb_massnahme_art' )  AND  "HWFDB-Layernahmen" = current_value('geplant_bestand_umgesetzt')
```

[image]

And it did not work, the drop-down is not appearing even though both `geplant_bestand_umgesetzt` and `hwfdb_massnahme_art` are filled.
[image]

Then I passed the exact value of the `geplant_bestand_umgesetzt` instead `current_value('geplant_bestand_umgesetzt')` and it worked like this.

```
"HWFDB-Massnahmenart"  =  current_value('hwfdb_massnahme_art' )  AND  "HWFDB-Layernahmen" = 'PL_RETENTION'
```

[image]

Why does the first option not work? Am I missing something?

Comment: Not sure what you are missing here. I have replicated your setup and it is working just fine with your first expression. Using 3.18 here. Btw I think it would be helpful in such cases to provide an example we can use for tests. Here is a GIF to proove it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/B87pX.gif

Comment: @MrXsquared thx a lot! The only difference we have I am using different domain tables to create the drop-downs https://i.imgur.com/tLuuvUv.png https://i.imgur.com/q1hbBY2.gif. It worked when I did as you did. So I can do what I want to only if I stick to one domain table?

Comment: @MrXsquared is there any way to show only distinct values in the drop-down in your example?

Comment: Not that I know of. I assume the basic concept of key-value pairs is beeing used here, where keys are supposed to be unique.

Comment: @MrXsquared Therefore,  I used different domain tables to create drop-downs. But with that solution. the filter expression is not working

Comment: Can you share an example project with example data?

Comment: @MrXsquared here you can find the project with data as well as the domain table I am using. Thanks a lot! I am going nuts with it https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/11WNEu9G50x8cEtA58BeWEfUFypVxR_Pe?usp=sharing

Comment: I have to admit thats some really weird stuff. I have the feeling current_value() is evaluating incorrectly, or more likely, I don't understand how it is supposed to work. To my understanding it should return the value currently entered to the form of a given field. But if you just use this function as default value of a text field (for testing) it does not return anything. As a conclusion I am afraid I dont know the solution...

Comment: Thanks a lot anyways @MrXsquared